# UserGroup by & order by to filter the MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have written a query to sum green status and red status in a column and to group them based on node name.

```
SELECT `Node`, Date(`DOR`) as "Date of Report",
    SUM(CASE WHEN `Color` = 'Green' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Pass'
 , SUM(CASE WHEN `Clor` = 'Red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Fail'
 , SUM(CASE WHEN `Color` = 'Green' or `Color` = 'Red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Total Checks'
FROM Monitor Where date(`TOI`) >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
Group by `Node`
```

How can I make the query better by filtering out the result where Red is 0 (I don't want to show if it's 0 as no attention is needed) and sort in Desc order based on Reds count?

Thanks,

Comment: Your query has many problems.  You are grouping by `Server`, but then selecting `Node` and `DOR`.  You should include sample data which explains what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Sorry, Its a mistake from my end. I am selecting node and also grouping by node. Corrected my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer your question about filtering Reds = 0 & ordering desc on Reds count:

```
SELECT `Node`, Date(`DOR`) as "Date of Report",
    SUM(CASE WHEN `Color` = 'Green' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Pass
 , SUM(CASE WHEN `Clor` = 'Red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Fail
 , SUM(CASE WHEN `Color` = 'Green' or `Color` = 'Red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Total Checks
FROM Monitor Where date(`TOI`) >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY
Group by `Server`
HAVING Fail > 0
order by Reds desc
```

But, As Tim mentioned, you've problems in your query like, You are grouping by Server, but then selecting `Node` and `DOR`.

Try to include the table structure & sample data so that we are able to understand the problem better & hence provide you with the correct answer

Comment: Sorry, Its a mistake from my end. I am selecting node and also grouping by node. Corrected my question. Thanks

Comment: My answer should work for you. Try it. Accept/upvote if it helps